# Google AdMob on Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, admob, windows-10

Microsoft Ad networks currently have $0.2 eCPM and 20% fill rate for me. Can't live on it. So I thought I should try other networks.

Is there a way to have Google AdMob in UWP Windows 10 app. Couldn't find anything and last question here is about 2 years ago.

Comment: I think AdMob is not supported in UWP apps, what about Microsoft Advertising?

Comment: @GeralexGR low fill rate and eCPM

Answer (score 3):

AdMob does not have an SDK for Windows UWP. At one time, there was a Windows Phone 8 SDK, but it's been sunsetted.